# Convert LocalDateTime to unix time format - groovy.lang.MissingMethodException

Tags: groovy, missingmethodexception

I want to get `toDate` to unix time format. I used this code:

```
import java.time.LocalDateTime;

LocalDateTime toDate = LocalDateTime.of(2021, 1, 31, 10, 0, 0)
long unixToDate = toDate.getTime() / 1000
```

But unfortunately I got this exception:

```
groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: java.time.LocalDateTime.getTime() is applicable for argument types: () values: []
Possible solutions: getHour(), getMinute(), getNano(), getYear(), clearTime(), get(java.time.temporal.TemporalField)
```

How can I amend my code?

Comment: `toDate.getTime()` returns a `java.time.LocalTime` instance. You can't "divide" that. If you want the Epoch seconds, use `toDate.toEpochSecond(ZoneOffset.UTC)` - just replace `ZoneOffset.UTC` with the correct offset where the `LocalDateTime` object is created.

Comment: I solved the problem using this: `long toDate = LocalDateTime.of(2020, 12, 31, 10, 0, 0).toEpochSecond(ZoneOffset.UTC)`